# How can I show img inside anchor tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to do something like:

```
<a href="something"> <img src="abc.jpg"/> </a>
```

But when I see Html.ActionLink I can find any overload that allows me to do that. How can I achieve the above using Action.HtmlLink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is not to use Html.Action link and write plain old HTML.

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Action", "Controller")%>">
    <img src="<%=Url.Content("~/Images/abc.jpg")%>" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achive the result your asking with ActionLink you've to write your own extension.
[Look at this article](http://agilefutures.com/index.php/2009/06/actionimage-aspnet-mvc)